# Strapi get relational data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I am new to Strapi and building an application were an authicated user should be able to save bookmarks. On the dashboard for the logged in user it should display a list of the user's bookmarks. However, I seem to be unable to get the relations `user has many bookmarks`. I have tried several ways, for instance creating a custom controller with the following:

```
const data = await strapi.services.bookmarks.find({ Users_premissions_user: { id: 1 } });
```

I have also tried with `/users/me`, but that only returns basic information about the user (no relational data). Basically, what I want to achieve is something similar to `SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE user_id = 1`.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to deeply populate the response. You can add a populate query to the API call

```
http://localhost:1337/api/[collection/single type]?populate=*
```

or..

if you're on StrapiV4 you can check out this populate deep [plugin](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-populate-deep)